# Xamarin Android Visual Studio 2019 Deploy Succeeded but does not start application

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

Application builds with no error and Visual Studio shows Deploy Succeeded in output but doesn't start on device. No errors in logic, so not sure what the issue is. Target api 30, device is api 25. Not finding much information elsewhere on what could be the root cause, tried running as admin, checked all options in Android Options -> Advanced -> Supported Architecture, updated Jdk path at a loss... tried on multiple devices as well as emulator.

```
Build started...
1>Starting deployment to SUNMI V2 ...
1>Deploying to SUNMI V2 ...
Build started.
Project "JamliteDeliveryPOS.Android.csproj" (Install target(s)):
Found Java SDK version 1.8.0.
Found Java SDK version 1.8.0.
 Looking for Android NDK...
 Looking for Android SDK...
Dex Fast Deployment Enabled: False
MonoAndroid Tools: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\
Android Platform API level: 30
TargetFrameworkVersion: v11.0
Android NDK: 
Android SDK: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\
Android SDK Build Tools: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\30.0.2\
Java SDK: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\
Application Java class: androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication
Project "JamliteDeliveryPOS.csproj" (GetTargetFrameworks target(s)):
Done building project "JamliteDeliveryPOS.csproj".
Project "JamliteDeliveryPOS.csproj" (GetTargetPath target(s)):
Done building project "JamliteDeliveryPOS.csproj".
Project "JamliteDeliveryPOS.csproj" (GetNativeManifest target(s)):
Done building project "JamliteDeliveryPOS.csproj".
Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.CSharp" that could not be resolved.
There was a conflict between "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
    "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was chosen because it was primary and "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was not.
    References which depend on "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Microsoft.CSharp.dll].
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Microsoft.CSharp.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Microsoft.CSharp.dll".
            Microsoft.CSharp
    References which depend on "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [].
        C:\Users\ansel\.nuget\packages
ewtonsoft.json\9.0.1\lib\portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\ansel\.nuget\packages
ewtonsoft.json\9.0.1\lib\portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81\Newtonsoft.Json.dll".
            C:\Users\ansel\.nuget\packages
ewtonsoft.json\9.0.1\lib\portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
            D:\Dropbox\JamLite\JamliteMobilePOS\JamliteDeliveryPOS\JamliteDeliveryPOS\bin\Debug
etstandard2.0\JamliteDeliveryPOS.dll
            C:\Users\ansel\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencymodel\2.1.0\lib
etstandard1.6\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.dll
            C:\Users\ansel\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlite.core\2.2.6\lib
etstandard2.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.dll
Skipping target "_VerifyXamarinAndroidSupportVersions" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_ResolveLibraryProjectImports" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_BuildLibraryImportsCache" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_GenerateAndroidResourceDir" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_GenerateLayoutBindings" because it has no outputs.
Skipping target "_AndroidXJetifyEmbeddedFiles" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_ConvertResourcesCases" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_CompileResources" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_PrepareUpdateAndroidResgen" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Checking Android SDK Build-tools version...
Selected Android SDK Build Tools Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\30.0.2\
Selected Android SDK Build Tools Version: 30.0.2
Android SDK Build Tools Version: 30.0.2 meets minimum requirements for Vector Drawables. OK.
Finished Checking Android SDK Build-tools version.
Skipping target "_UpdateAndroidResgen" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Touching "obj\Debug\110\stamp\_AndroidXJetifyEmbeddedFiles.stamp".
  Adding assembly reference for JamliteDeliveryPOS.Android, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.ComponentModel.Annotations, recursively...
    Adding assembly reference for System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.AppContext, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.Runtime.Extensions, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.IO.FileSystem, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.Collections, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.Reflection, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.IO, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.Linq, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.Diagnostics.Debug, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.Threading, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.Reflection.Extensions, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.Linq.Queryable, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.Runtime.Serialization, recursively...
    Adding assembly reference for System.ServiceModel.Internals, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for FormsViewGroup, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for JamliteDeliveryPOS, recursively...
    Adding assembly reference for netstandard, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.Data, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Numerics, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Transactions, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.Data.DataSetExtensions, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.Drawing.Common, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.IO.Compression.FileSystem, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.ComponentModel.Composition, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.Web.Services, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Java.Interop, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Microsoft.CSharp, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Microsoft.Data.Sqlite, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions, recursively...
    Adding assembly reference for System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, recursively...
    Adding assembly reference for System.Runtime.InteropServices, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, recursively...
    Adding assembly reference for System.Data.SqlClient, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Microsoft.Extensions.Options, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Mono.Android, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for mscorlib, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Newtonsoft.Json, recursively...
    Adding assembly reference for System.Threading.Tasks, recursively...
    Adding assembly reference for System.Xml.XDocument, recursively...
    Adding assembly reference for System.Globalization, recursively...
    Adding assembly reference for System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives, recursively...
    Adding assembly reference for System.Linq.Expressions, recursively...
    Adding assembly reference for System.Dynamic.Runtime, recursively...
    Adding assembly reference for System.ObjectModel, recursively...
    Adding assembly reference for System.Text.RegularExpressions, recursively...
    Adding assembly reference for System.Xml.ReaderWriter, recursively...
    Adding assembly reference for System.Text.Encoding, recursively...
    Adding assembly reference for System.Text.Encoding.Extensions, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for PropertyChanged, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for RabbitMQ.Client, recursively...
    Adding assembly reference for System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Remotion.Linq, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for SignaturePad, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for SignaturePad.Forms, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_green, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for SQLitePCLRaw.core, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.Buffers, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.Collections.Immutable, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.Core, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, recursively...
    Adding assembly reference for System.Diagnostics.Tracing, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System, recursively...
    Adding assembly reference for Mono.Security, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.Interactive.Async, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.IO.Compression, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.Memory, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.Net.Http, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.Runtime, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.Threading.Channels, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.Xml, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for System.Xml.Linq, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Common, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Runtime, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Common, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.LiveData, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Runtime, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.ViewModel, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.AsyncLayoutInflater, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Collections, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.CoordinaterLayout, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.CursorAdapter, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomView, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Design, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.DocumentFile, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.DrawerLayout, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Interpolator, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Loader, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.LocalBroadcastManager, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Print, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.SlidingPaneLayout, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.SwipeRefreshLayout, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.VersionedParcelable, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.ViewPager, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Annotation, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Annotation.Experimental, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.AppCompatResources, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Arch.Core.Common, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Arch.Core.Runtime, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.AsyncLayoutInflater, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.CardView, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Collection, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.CoordinatorLayout, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Core, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.CursorAdapter, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.CustomView, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.DocumentFile, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.DrawerLayout, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Interpolator, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.Core.UI, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.Core.Utils, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V4, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Common, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Runtime, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.ViewModel, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.ViewModelSavedState, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Loader, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.LocalBroadcastManager, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Media, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.MediaRouter, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.MultiDex, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.Common, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.Runtime, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.UI, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Palette, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Preference, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Print, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.SavedState, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.SlidingPaneLayout, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.SwipeRefreshLayout, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Transition, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.VectorDrawable.Animated, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.VectorDrawable, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.VersionedParcelable, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.ViewPager, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.ViewPager2, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Forms.Core, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Forms.Platform, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Forms.Xaml, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Google.Android.Material, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Google.Guava.ListenableFuture, recursively...
Skipping target "_CopyConfigFiles" because it has no inputs.
Skipping target "_ConvertPdbFiles" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_LinkAssembliesNoShrink" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_CopyConfigFiles" because it has no inputs.
Skipping target "_AndroidXCecilfy" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_GenerateJavaStubs" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_ManifestMerger" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_ConvertCustomView" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_AndroidXJetifyManifest" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_AddStaticResources" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_GeneratePackageManagerJava" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_GenerateAndroidAssetsDir" because it has no outputs.
Skipping target "_PrepareCreateBaseApk" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_CreateBaseApk" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_CompileJava" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_CompileNativeAssemblySources" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_CreateApplicationSharedLibraries" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_AndroidXJetifyJavaLibraryRules" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_AndroidXJetifyProguardRules" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_CompileToDalvik" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Touching "obj\Debug\110\android\bin\apk_per_abi.flag".
Skipping target "_BuildApkEmbed" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_CopyPackage" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Touching "obj\Debug\110\android_debug_keystore.flag".
Skipping target "_Sign" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Skipping target "_Upload" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Done building project "JamliteDeliveryPOS.Android.csproj".
Build succeeded.
1>Deployment was successful to SUNMI V2.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: You can try to delete the obj and  bin folders, then restart VS, and rebuild it.

Comment: Tried this, doesn't work... this has me beat it seems, could it be a VS bug?

Comment: You can try to restart your pc and try again. If the problem persist, try to repair your Visual Studio.For more check:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019 .

Answer (score 3):

I once had the exact same problem. In my case, the problem was, that in the AndroidManifest.xml file, there were two '<application' sections. After removing one of the sections, the app started without problems. Don't know if this is your case, but maybe it will help someone.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BIMZ.jpg